# how to show both device and external storage in my listview

Tags: android

[image: I need something like this]

I want to show both the external and internal storage at the very beginning of my activity.

I am using a path "/mnt/" to get but unfortunately this lists only internal storage.

I also tried the following but it is not working.

```
Boolean isSDPresent = android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageState().equals(android.os.Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED);
if(isSDPresent)
{                   
      path=android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath();
}
else
{
      path = android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get access to the `EXTERNAL_STORAGE` you need to have permissions for it.

> Writing to this path requires the WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission, and starting in read access requires the READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission, which is automatically granted if you hold the write permission.

If you only want to show that there is a external storage you could also use

> Starting in KITKAT, if your application only needs to store internal data, consider using getExternalFilesDir(String) or getExternalCacheDir(), which require no permissions to read or write.

and remove the `getAbsoultePath()` since `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()` will give the correct one

See the docs for examples

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Environment.html#getExternalStorageDirectory()

Comment: I am not able to show both the internal storage and sdcard at the same time. What ever i am doing is only able to show internal storage only. i have given all permission and all.